# Delete all events in iCal

Tags: ical

How can I delete all events in iCal? I have a bunch of events (some reoccurring) that I want to delete. I don't want to have to manually delete/cut each event.

I tried declining the events but that just turns them gray.

I'm running OS X 10.6.6.

Answer (score 1):

Applescript:

```
tell application "iCal"
   tell calendar "My Calendar" -- your calendar here
      set theEvents to every event
      repeat with current_event in theEvents           
         delete current_event
      end repeat
   end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by deleting `~/Library/Calendars` as suggested in [here](http://forums.omnigroup.com/showthread.php?t=5400).