# Move all events from one iCal calendar to another

Tags: macos, ical

I would like to consolidate several iCal calendars.  So, I'm wondering if there is a way to move all events from one iCal calendar to another.  I'm not interested in changing the time, etc. of any of the events, as asked [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12966/move-a-bunch-of-ical-events-at-once), and I'm not interested in simply deleting all the events in my calendar, as asked [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9169/delete-all-events-in-ical).

I'm running iCal Version 5.0 (1535) on OS X 10.7.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Select one of the calendars you want to merge
- choose File->Export...->Export
- Make sure the filename matches the calender you've chosen above. The calendar will be exported to a .ics file
- Choose File->Import...->Import and find the file you've just saved.
- ical will ask you to which calendar it should add the events. Just select the another one of the calendars you want to merge.
- repeat until all calendars are merged.

Comment: This didn't work for me. iCal 5.0.1.
exported "No Category" imported it specifying Work and the events only show up when No Category is selected under calenders :(
k